# Rxjava 2 Maybe.toSingle error

Tags: java, rx-java2

why maybe.toSingle() throw error no such element?    I tried to handle doOnError but doesn't work!!

```
     Single<Integer> singleOdd = Single.just(1);
    Single<Integer> singleEven = Single.just(2);
      Single.concat(singleOdd.filter(integer -> integer%2 ==0).toSingle(),singleEven).doOnError(throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace()).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why maybe.toSingle() throw error no such element?

`filter()` on a `Single` has two outcomes, either it passes and you have one item, or it doesn't pass and you have an empty `Maybe`. Converting back to `Single` mandates that you have exactly one item or an error.

> I tried to handle doOnError but doesn't work!!

`doOnError` is not error handling from the stream's perspective but a peek into the error channel. You have to use `onErrorResumeNext` or `retry` to react to an error case.